# How to check if a dataclass is frozen?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Is there a way to check if a Python dataclass has been set to frozen? If not, would it be valuable to have a method like is_frozen in the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) module to perform this check?

e.g.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_frozen

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

person = Person('Alice', 25)
if not is_frozen(person):
    person.name = 'Bob'
```

One way to check if a dataclass has been set to frozen is to try to modify one of its attributes and catch the `FrozenInstanceError` exception that will be raised if it's frozen.

e.g.

```py
from dataclasses import FrozenInstanceError
is_frozen = False
try:
    person.name = 'check_if_frozen'
except FrozenInstanceError:
    is_frozen = True
```

However, if the dataclass is not frozen, the attribute will be modified, which may be unwanted just for the sake of performing the check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes looks like you can retrieve parameters' information from `__dataclass_params__`.

It returns an instance of [`_DataclassParams`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py#L336) type which is nothing but an object for holding the values of `init`, `repr`, `eq`, `order`, `unsafe_hash`, `frozen` attributes:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int


print(Person.__dataclass_params__)
print(Person.__dataclass_params__.frozen)
```

output:

```
_DataclassParams(init=True,repr=True,eq=True,order=False,unsafe_hash=False,frozen=True)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this should be mentioned somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know why this is a dunder attribute, but if it's not documented, it's because it's not intended for public use. (The next version of Python could rename the attribute without warning, for example.)